# OpenCV 3.1 optimization

Tags: performance, python-2.7, numpy, opencv3.1

I'm currently trying to implement an algorithm from a paper with OpenCV 3.1 on python 2.7 but the process is taking way too long.

The section of my code that's giving me trouble looks something like this:

```
width, height = mr.shape[:2]
Pm = []
for i in d:
    M = np.float32([[1,0,-d[i]], [0,1,1]])
    mrd = cv2.warpAffine(mr, M, (height,width))
    C = cv2.subtract(ml, mrd)
    C = cv2.pow(C,2)
    C = np.divide(C, sigma_m)
    C = p0 + (1-p0)**(-C)
    Pm.append(C)
```

Where `ml`, `mr` and `mrd` are cv2 objects and `d`, `p0` and `sigma_m` are integers.

The division and final equation in the last 3 lines are the real troublemakers here. Every iteration of this cycle is independent so in theory I could just split the 'for loop' through a few processors, but that seems like a lazy approach where I would just bypass the problem instead of fixing it.

Does anyone know a way to perform those computations faster?

Comment: It also depends how you built OpenCV so you could post the output of `getBuildInformation()`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell The output of `cv2.getBuildInformation()` is too big to write in a comment. Are you thinking of anything specific from that output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can leverage [`numexpr` module](https://github.com/pydata/numexpr/wiki/Numexpr-Users-Guide) to efficiently perform all of those latter arithmetic operations as one evaluate expression.

Thus, these steps :

```
C = cv2.subtract(ml, mrd)
C = cv2.pow(C,2)
C = np.divide(C, sigma_m)
C = p0 + (1-p0)**(-C)
```

could be replaced by one expression -

```
import numexpr as ne
C = ne.evaluate('p0 +(1-p0)**(-((ml-mrd)**2)/sigma_m)')
```

Let's verify things. The original approach as func -

```
def original_app(ml, mrd, sigma_m, p0):
    C = cv2.subtract(ml, mrd)
    C = cv2.pow(C,2)
    C = np.divide(C, sigma_m)
    C = p0 + (1-p0)**(-C)
    return C
```

Verification -

```
In [28]: # Setup inputs
    ...: S = 1024 # Size parameter
    ...: ml = np.random.randint(0,255,(S,S))/255.0
    ...: mrd = np.random.randint(0,255,(S,S))/255.0
    ...: sigma_m = 0.45
    ...: p0 = 0.56
    ...: 

In [29]: out1 = original_app(ml, mrd, sigma_m, p0)

In [30]: out2 = ne.evaluate('p0 +(1-p0)**(-((ml-mrd)**2)/sigma_m)')

In [31]: np.allclose(out1, out2)
Out[31]: True
```

Timings across various sizes of datasets -

```
In [19]: # Setup inputs
    ...: S = 1024 # Size parameter
    ...: ml = np.random.randint(0,255,(S,S))/255.0
    ...: mrd = np.random.randint(0,255,(S,S))/255.0
    ...: sigma_m = 0.45
    ...: p0 = 0.56
    ...: 

In [20]: %timeit original_app(ml, mrd, sigma_m, p0)
10 loops, best of 3: 67.1 ms per loop

In [21]: %timeit ne.evaluate('p0 +(1-p0)**(-((ml-mrd)**2)/sigma_m)')
100 loops, best of 3: 12.9 ms per loop

In [22]: # Setup inputs
    ...: S = 512 # Size parameter

In [23]: %timeit original_app(ml, mrd, sigma_m, p0)
100 loops, best of 3: 15.3 ms per loop

In [24]: %timeit ne.evaluate('p0 +(1-p0)**(-((ml-mrd)**2)/sigma_m)')
100 loops, best of 3: 3.39 ms per loop

In [25]: # Setup inputs
    ...: S = 256 # Size parameter

In [26]: %timeit original_app(ml, mrd, sigma_m, p0)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.65 ms per loop

In [27]: %timeit ne.evaluate('p0 +(1-p0)**(-((ml-mrd)**2)/sigma_m)')
1000 loops, best of 3: 878 µs per loop
```

Around **`5x`** speedup across various sizes with better speedups for larger arrays!

Also, as a side-note, I would advise using initialized arrays instead of appending as you are doing at the final step. Thus, we could initialize before going into the loop with something like `out = np.zeros((len(d), width, height))` / `np.empty` and at the final step assign into the output array with : `out[iteration_ID] = C`.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I tried a quick implementation with numexpr and there was a speedup of roughly 4x.

Comment: @Mira Awesome! Its hard to beat `cv2` in most scenarios, so its good to see `numexpr` giving it a good competition and winning!

Comment: Just a quick question about your answer regarding np.empty(). I didn't really understand how you would use it. Is it instead of the np.zeros() initialization?

Also, tried the np.zeros() approach and there may be a small boost in performance, but we're talking about a difference of centiseconds when the execution of the program is measured in seconds. Any how thank you for the suggestion ;)

Comment: @Mira Yeah, if you were successful with using `np.zeros((len(d), width, height))`, then we could use `np.empty` instead of `np.zeros` with the same shape parameters, but the gain with it would be insignificant as the heavy work is done with the arithmetic operrations, which we are improving here. Give it a try, keep playing, that's how we all learn anyway :)

Comment: I decided to give a try to `np.empty` and to my surprise the difference was actually quite noticeable. The program seems to be on average a good 200 milliseconds faster. Thanks yet again!

Comment: @Mira Impressive really! Good going! :)